# Get Size of Data from Database that will be fetched

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show resultset size that is going to be fetched from mysql using php.
Let's say we are executing around 50 query that will take time around 60-120 sec.,

And we have to show the resultset size and expected tiem to transfer that data to user.

What should be the best way to achieve this.

Approach one:-

I tried with precalculated for every user and save it to a table, but database is updating is updating every 15 min, and we can not gather resultset size for all user record in 15 min.

Approach Two-

Calculate on the way:- By using this, user will wait untill we calculate. it is not desirable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the char_length functionality and write your query as follows

`select sum(
    char_length(column1)+
    char_length(column2)+
    char_length(column3)+
    char_length(column4) ... )
    from table_name`

Comment: This is not my question, b/c it will also take time to calculate from 50-60 table based on queries.But can u elaborate this , how can i do the same for sub queries and join, Thanks for your reply!